# create new page within my admin page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a new plug for my project I have the like in the admin menu and i have created the landing page I would like to know how i can create a new page within my plugin.

So if I was to click on View All Images how could i navigate to a new page within my plugin?

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'test_plugin_setup_menu');

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts');

function test_plugin_setup_menu(){
        add_menu_page( 'Test Plugin Page', 'Test Plugin', 'manage_options', 'test-plugin', 'test_init' );
}

function test_init(){
    echo "<a href='#'>View All Images</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [plugins_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) function

```
function test_init(){
    echo "<a href='<?=plugins_url();?>/your_file.php'>View All Images</a>";
}
```